# Thickness and Diameter of hollowed Galvanised Steel pole/tube required to sustain 80kg passive weight aswell as suddenly absorb of 60-80kg body weight

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, civil-engineering

Here is a diagram of the designed frame.

[image]

Label A) points to the 4 horizontal bars underneath the transparent brown sheet (the ground)

Label B) shows the ovals (surface level) on all other bits of structure. The arrows show which directions, that pretty much every bar, will need to be able to absorb sudden body weight from any one small position

The length bars are 6.5m

The height bars are 6.5m

and the width bars would be 2-3m

I have the options of 25mm outer diameter - 40mm outer diameter

and the options of 1.6mm - 3mm thickness

I would want to mount about 50kg of weight in equipment maximum, as well as body weight from 60kg-70kg which would need to be suddenly absorbed with each movement.

It is intended to be a rock climbing frame with and so the 60-80kg of body weight would need to be absorbed within concentrated positions (both hands and all body weight within the same 5cm squared)

My questions are

1. Would 3m width of the whole frame give more stability
2. Would I need to add more bars to connect each vertical bar to each vertical bar, and each horizontal to each horizontal, in order for the frame not to sway not bend, or would the additional 2 poles/tubes of support on each corner be enough (I think I would probably need each of the horizontal bars connected)
3. Would 25mm outer diameter, as well as 1.6mm - 2mm thickness be sufficient because going 40mm, or 4mm thickness, would double my required budget
4. What ratio of the height tubes should be underground, I would want at least 5 meters of the 6.5 accessible
5. What angle should the 2 additional structure poles on each corner go downward from, and how long would that bar need to be considering how high the top would be as suggested in question

Comment: If the length is 6.5m then even scaffold tube won’t cope.

Comment: Thanks for your time mike.

Even with those additional diagonal supports? Or perhaps a few extra ones connecting horizontal poles to each other and verticals to each other?
It would be about 5m above surface I would imagine

Comment: You ask the wrong question. Should be ,"will 1- 1/2 or 2" sch 40 NPS pipe be strong enough" ? There are very limited options unless you have access to some industrial source.

Comment: Will there be a climbing wall attached to the tubes or will the tubes be loaded directly by someone hanging/standing on them?